# Problem embedding javascript for loops in liftweb static content

Tags: javascript, scala, lift

Here's what I tried...
I put this in a file called `<mySbtBasedProjdir>/src/main/webapp/static/simpleForLoop.html`

```
<lift:surround with="default" at="content">
```

Why is this a problem in liftweb?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var i=0;
  for (i=0;i<=5;i++) {
    document.write("The number is " + i);
    document.write("<br />");
  }
</script>

</lift:surround>
```

The error I get starts with:

```
scala.xml.dtd.ValidationException: :5:14: name expectednet.liftweb.util.PCDataXmlParser.reportSyntaxError(PCDataMarkupParser.scala:174)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose it inside CDATA tags I think

```
<![CDATA[
<script etc ...
</script>
]]>
```

So the parser ignores it.